# What is the difference between ones and zeroes on the superdiagonal in a Jordan normal form matrix?

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

I've observed that in Jordan normal form the eigenvalues are obviously on the diagonal, but on the superdiagonal there can sometimes be only ones, sometimes be only zeroes and sometimes both. What is the significance of this? How does it relate to the basis, Jordan blocks etc?

Comment: I think this is covered in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form?

Comment: The picture at the top of the article illustrates what a Jordan block fairly clearly.  Did you want clarification beyond that @Heuristics?